# Can I replace %20 with + in url parameters?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

In order to make my dynamic URLs search engine friendly, I need to replace(or redirect) spaces (`%20`) that appear in the URL with a plus sign (`+`).

For example :

change this dynamic URL: `www.example.com/search?keys=milton%20keynes`

to simply: `www.example.com/search?keys=milton+keynes`

Can do this with `mod_rewrite` code?

Comment: This should probably be done on the client side and not on the server side.

Comment: Small note: "+" is a plus sign, not a dash "-" :)

Answer (score 5):

To capture the + sign in the request, use urldecode().

For instance:

```
$keys = urldecode($_GET['keys']);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in whatever replacements in the search requests.
Just because search bots do not use search forms on your site.

for the any other use (urls generated by your site) it is okay to use + instead of %20